# Changing the Datatype of table column

Tags: sql-server-2005

A very simple MSSQL command is giving error.

> create table emp (empid char(6));
>
> insert into emp values(3);
>
> > > ALTER TABLE emp MODIFY empid char(10); //The error line :@

Error >Line 1: Incorrect syntax near 'empid'.

It's mindboggling, either the day is not mine or All Hail MS :P

Any resolutions?

Comment: This would probably get more response over on Stack Overflow - though you don't have to do anything (other than have a linked account). It might also be beneficial if you added more information.

Answer (score 1):

Change it to

```
ALTER TABLE emp ALTER COLUMN empid char(10)
```

Have a look at

[ALTER TABLE (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273.aspx)

and search for *ALTER COLUMN* examples