# Decimal value wrong on insert - MySQL

Tags: mysql, .net, sql

When I insert a value of 10 or 10.0 to a decimal(10.0) column I get 9.9999999... - is there any way to get a 10 when inserting it?

Using entity framework, .NET 4.5, MySQL > 5

Table definition: decimal(10,9)

Comment: What's your table definition?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525180/mysql-decimal-with-accuracy-of-10-digits-after-the-comma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've posted link with expalation.

You can use `double` instead of `decimal`.

Comment: is there an option to change the column decimal definition, I get Change column type is not supported

Comment: In phpMyAdmin running on my server, I can do it. Look: http://stepolabs.com/upload/double.png

Comment: can't understand the difference between double and decimal :[

Comment: Now, you don't need to understand it ^^ you have to change it. If you are not running phpMyAdmin, here is way how to do that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979883/changing-the-datatype-of-table-column
Difference is in range and storing of data.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/921a8ffc-9829-4145-bdc9-a96c1ec174a5/
 read the discussion, but now, my bed is waiting for me, so good night :)